# Will reloading Apache load a newly installed php-xml module or is an Apache restart required

Tags: php, apache, service

I'd rather users not see errors if they try to load a page for the 5 seconds apache is restarting, but I don't know for sure if reloading is enough to load in the new module.  RHEL 6 HTTPD 2.2.15 php 5.3.3.

Comment: How is PHP set up within Apache (module, fastcgi, etc.)?

Comment: It is setup via module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reloading Apache the php.ini is reparsed and it will load any new modules you've added.